# How to solve Xcode error message 'url' instance member cannot be used on type 'view controller'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I typed the following swift code in Xcode and it shows error message

> 'url' instance member cannot be used on type 'view controller'

here's my code-

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")!

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in


}
```

Comment: Don't do `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url)` at the root of the controller. Do it inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for Swift 3 and the error message of Xcode 8.2.1 (current version):

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")!
var task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
    (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
}
```

and the error message in line 2 is now:

> Cannot use instance member 'url' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

This makes it more clear, I think. Creating the `task` must be done later in a function like `viewDidLoad`.

This code would work (well, at least it compiles):

```
var task: URLSessionTask?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com") {
        task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            // Handle response and errors here
        }
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Question Tag is Swift 2

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned why I explained it on Swift 3: the error message leads to the solution and it resolves in the same way.

Comment: You are not even calling resume. BTW Swift is a type inferred language. You just need to pass the parameters names, no need to pass the types.  `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in`

Answer (score 0):

It should be called in the below way.

```
let url = "www.example.com"     
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)! )
let urlSession = URLSession.shared        
let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: rssRequest) { (data, response, error) in 
    //get your response and error here 
}
```

Steps:

1. Create the URL request
2. Create the shared session
3. download the contents from the URL